# Numeric data type and decimals

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm sure this must be a simple one but I can't seem to figure it out. I have a column full of fractions like: 0.6333333333. Am I correct in making the data type NUMERIC? Or should it be something else? Because it keeps giving me this error:

```
Could not convert value '0.6333333333' to numeric
```

Should I decrease the decimals or change the type to something else rather?

Comment: This code works fine for me in BigQuery:  select `cast('0.6333333333' as numeric)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `NUMERIC` data type in BigQuery gives you everything you want, so long as you want a precision of 38 digits and up to 9 digits to the right of the decimal point.  To quote the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#numeric-type):

> The NUMERIC data type is an exact numeric value with 38 digits of precision and 9 decimal digits of scale.

Your value has 10 digits to the right of the decimal point.  So, this cannot be exactly represented.  What can you do?  Here are some options:

- Forget about the tenth digit.  It was nice while it lasted, but BQ doesn't support it.
- Multiply the values by 10 or some other multiple of 10, so they can be represented exactly (you know, the values represent millimeters rather than kilometers).
- Store the values as strings and convert to floats when you need to do arithmetic.
- Store the values as floats and hope the value is "close enough" (there should be enough precision for this value).